# Login servlet gives error as null exception

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a login page and when I put the correct credentials in it gives `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException` error.

Here is the Authenticate.java (POJO class) which contains the methods to valid and read data from the database table:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.Exoticatravels;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;

/**
 *
 * @author sufiyaan
 */
public class Authenticate {

    private String firstName;
    private String pass;

    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Exotica_TravelsPU");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();


    public boolean findUser(String enteredEmail){
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.email =" + "'" + enteredEmail + "'");
        List results = query.getResultList();  

        if(results.isEmpty()){
            return false;
        }

        Iterator it = results.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()){
             Users user = (Users) it.next();
             firstName = user.getFirstName().toString();
             pass = user.getPassword().toString();
        }
            em.close();
            emf.close();
        return true;

    }

    public boolean authUser(String enteredPass){

        if(enteredPass.equals(pass)){
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getPass() {
        return pass;
    }

}
```

I am new to this and what I doubt is there is an error somewhere around here while assigning the value to the firstName variable.

```
user = (Users) it.next();
firstName = user.getFirstName().toString();
```

Here is my Login Servlet:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.Exoticatravels;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 *
 * @author sufiyaan
 */
public class Login extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

          String email = request.getParameter("email");
          String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
        Authenticate auth = new Authenticate();

        String firstName = auth.getFirstName();

        boolean isUser = auth.findUser(email);
        boolean isAuthenticated = auth.authUser(pass);

         if(isUser == false || isAuthenticated == false){
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.html");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("firstName", firstName);

        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("welcome.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

Here is the log for the program if it is helpful:

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[Login]: Servlet.service() for servlet Login threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.welcome_jsp._jspService(welcome_jsp.java:80)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at com.Exoticatravels.Login.doPost(Login.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Please help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at this line of generated servlet - welcome_jsp.java:80

Comment: @SundararajGovindasamy in the welcome.jsp I have pulled the value of firstName through session which is stored at the login servlet. What I doubt is there is something wrong in the iterator in the authenticate class for firstName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be like this in Login servlet, whats happening is that you're setting a null string `firstName` to your session, i think this will solve the problem

```
    boolean isUser = auth.findUser(email);
    boolean isAuthenticated = auth.authUser(pass);

    String firstName = auth.getFirstName();
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it.